# Why does my custom Ansible module fail?

Tags: ansible

I am learning ansible so I wrote the most simple playbook and module I could think of, and it failed.

My playbook

```
---
- hosts: demo
  tasks:
    - name: install demo
      action: install
```

My module

```
echo "changed=True msg=OK"
```

The following seems fine :

- bash script mode is 755
- playbook is linked to module correctly

This is the output:

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "", "module_stdout": "changed=True msg=OK\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "parsed": false}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I make this work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The output of a module [must be JSON](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_modules.html#common-pitfalls).

Try this:

```
echo "{\"changed\": false, \"msg\" : \"ok\"}"
```

From the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_modules.html#common-pitfalls):

> You should also never do this in a module:
>
> ```
> print "some status message"
> ```
>
> Because the output is supposed to be valid JSON.

and:

> If a module returns stderr or otherwise fails to produce valid JSON, the actual output will still be shown in Ansible, but the command will not succeed.

Comment: please correct your answer to be a valid json in the echo line. `echo "{\"changed\": false}"`

Comment: I think the non-JSON output was removed in 1.8. It was called "baby JSON".