# Why does my Ansible playbook always return 'error'?

Tags: bash, shell, ansible

When trying to run a playbook I always get an error. And I don't understand why I get the error.

My Playbook

```
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local

  tasks:
    #Call ansible module "userinfo" with parameter "username="
    - name: 'Ansible module in shell'
      action: userinfo username=ansible
      register: userInfoVariable

    - name: 'Abort execution if user does not exist'
      fail: msg="User does not exist"
      when: userInfoVariable.isUserExist == False

    - name: 'Execute task if user exist'
      #action: someaction
      shell: echo 'User exist - Replace shell with your action here.'
      register: userExist
      when: userInfoVariable.isUserExist == True

    - debug: var=userExist
```

I want to run this shell-script as module

```
#!/bin/bash

source ${1}

if id -u $username >/dev/null 2>&1; then
isUserExist="True"
else
isUserExist="False"
fi

echo "changed=True msg=OK isUserExist='$isUserExist'"
```

And this is the result after running the playbook

```
18:14:38-admin@serv17:~/ans-playbooks$ ansible-playbook test-cust-module.yml

PLAY [127.0.0.1] **************************************************************

TASK: [Ansible module in shell] ***********************************************
failed: [127.0.0.1] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
changed=True msg=OK isUserExist='True'


FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
           to retry, use: --limit @/home/admin/test-cust-module.retry

127.0.0.1                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

My script is run based on this output

```
changed=True msg=OK isUserExist='True'
```

But this error is not expected

```
failed: [127.0.0.1] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
```

Why does it occur?

Comment: What is the `userinfo` action?  Is it that shell script?

Comment: I suspect your shell script is returning a non-zero exit code. What happens when you run it directly from the command line... Why are you sourcing $1?

Comment: @jwodder Yes, that is a shell script

Comment: @rumdrums Sourcing $1 is the way Ansible passes vars to shellscripts within modules AFAIK. When I run the script locally I have to replace 
`source ${1}` by `username=$1`. In that case the script returns "True" if the questioned username exists on the system. The exit code is always 0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my custom Ansible module fail?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34960794/why-does-my-custom-ansible-module-fail)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"parsed": false` means Ansible can't parse the output of the module. The reason of failure is that the output is always expected as a JSON string. From [common-pitfalls](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_modules.html#common-pitfalls) section of module development:

> You should also never do this in a module:
>
> `print "some status message"`
>
> Because the output is supposed to be valid JSON.
>
> Modules must not output anything on standard error, because the system will merge standard out with standard error and prevent the JSON from parsing. Capturing standard error and returning it as a variable in the JSON on standard out is fine, and is, in fact, how the command module is implemented.
>
> If a module returns stderr or otherwise fails to produce valid JSON, the actual output will still be shown in Ansible, but the command will not succeed.

So you need to change your last `echo` to output a valid JSON string. Something like this:

```
echo "{\"changed\": true, \"msg\": \"OK\", \"isUserExist\": \"'$isUserExist'\"}"
```

Comment: FWIW, before 1.8 non-JSON output was allowed.

Comment: @tedder42 thanks for the info. I didn't know that. In this case I think OP is using a later version.

Comment: I agree- it's safe to assume people are on at least 1.9 at this point. Thought I'd mention it for anyone who happens along this.